# How to convert compact Json to pretty print codename one

Tags: json, codenameone, pretty-print

I want to know how to convert a string of compact Json to pretty print so that I can parse it. I have searched for this question in stack overflow but it doesn't seem like anyone has asked it for codename one.
Right now I have a string of compact Json but it can not be parsed. This is the code:

```
String JsonData = "{\"document\":{ \"type\":\"PLAIN_TEXT\", \"content\":\"Ask not what your country can do for you, ask what you can do for your country.\" },\"encodingType\":\"UTF8\"}";
            JsonResponse = Rest.
                post("https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:analyzeSyntax?key=[API KEY").
                    jsonContent().
                    body(JsonData).
                    getAsJsonMap();
            String JsonString = (JsonResponse.getResponseData()).toString();
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            Map<String, Object> results = null;
            try {
                results = parser.parseJSON(new StringReader(JsonString));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("fail");
            }
            System.out.println("results   "+results);
```

But when I run this code I get a bunch of these responses:

```
[EDT] 0:0:3,269 - Expected null for key value while parsing JSON token at row: 1 column: 5 buffer: e
```

and

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ee0"
```

How should I convert my string of compact Json (JsonString) to pretty print so that I can parse it? Alternatively, is there a way to directly parse the response (JsonResponse)?
Thank You

Comment: could you post your full code? this obviously doesn't compile.

Comment: My program is pretty long but this is a free standing part: nothing else in the program affects this request.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing out a map not a JSON string as the JSON data is already parsed. If you just want to look at the network protocol for debugging the best way to do that is open the `Network Monitor` in the simulator where you will see all HTTP requests and can copy out the response body JSON.

However you can still convert a `Map` back to JSON using:

```
Log.p("results   " + JSONParser.mapToJson(results));
```

Notice you should use `Log.p()` and `Log.e()` to log strings/exceptions as that would work better on the devices.

Comment: Thank you. That line of code was helpful. I think that I was asking the wrong questions though. I wanted to put the response into a Map<String, Object> and I did not realize that you could just do Response = Map<String, Object>.